# Python loop keeps returning incorrectly, how can I amend this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

```
sandwichType=""
totalCost=0
sandwiches=["Baguette", "Bagel", "Sub", "Wrap", "White"]
sandwichVAL={"Baguette":3.50, "Bagel":2.10, "Sub":3.99, "Wrap":4.15, "White":0.90}
choice=""
while choice!="Baguette" or choice!="Bagel" or choice!="Sub" or choice!="Wrap" or choice!="White":
  choice=str(input("What type of sandwich would you like?\n>Baguette - £3.50\n>Bagel    - £2.10\n>Sub      - £3.99\n>Wrap     - £4.15\n>White    - £0.90\n"))
  if choice!="Baguette" or choice!="Bagel" or choice!="Sub" or choice!="Wrap" or choice!="White":
    print("Unfortunately, that is not a valid choice! Please pick again and remember to capitalise the first letter!")
  else:
    print()
totalCost+=sandwichVAL[choice]
print(totalCost)
```

This code keeps returning

```
Unfortunately, that is not a valid choice! Please pick again and remember to capitalise the first letter!
```

even when the choice variable is correct. What edits should I make to make it print the total cost?

Comment: Your logic is wrong. The `or` condition returns `True` if any of those conditions are `True`. You should change the `or`s to `and`s. But even better, use `in`. Eh this comment is getting long, I'll write an answer. Edit: Multiple people beat me to it. Also you don't the list `sandwiches`-
 the dict `sandwichVAL` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your logic:

```
if choice != A or choice != B ...
```

`choice` can match only *one* of your hard-coded alternatives; this test *must* be `True` for any value of `choice`.
Instead, try something like

```
if choice not in ["Baguette", "Bagel", "Sub", ...]:
```

Better yet, use the list you already have:

```
if choice not in sandwiches:
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if choice!="Baguette" or choice!="Bagel" or choice!="Sub" or choice!="Wrap" or choice!="White":
```

This logic is incorrect.  The branch will be taken when *any* of these expressions is true.  e.g. if `choice = "Bagel"`, then `(choice != "Sub") == True`.

You probably want `and`s instead of `or`s.  Even better, since you have already defined a list of valid sandwiches, you can write:

```
if choice not in sandwiches:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if the choice is valid via:

```
if choice not in sandwiches:
    print("Unfortunately, ...")
```